# Redondear esquinas en gráfico de barras

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Comencé a utilizar la librería *Chart.js* en mi proyecto personal, estuve repasando su documentación y me fue bien al momento de hacer mis primeros gráficos. Mi duda es que si existe alguna manera de dar bordes a las esquinas de las barras verticales en mi gráfico, he estado investigando acerca de esto y no logré encontrar solución alguna.

Mi gráfico es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código que tengo del gráfico es el siguiente:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [<?php echo $nombreArr; ?>],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: [<?php echo $cantidadArr; ?>],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.2
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.2,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad [borderRadius](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#borderradius) del dataset

Esta propiedad acepta tanto un número como un objeto

- `borderRadius: 5`
- `borderRadius: {topLeft: 5, topRight:5, bottomLeft: 2, bottomRight:4 }`

Ejemplo:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["RETEN DE EMBOLO", "RETEN DE EMPOLO"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: [4,8],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: {topLeft: 10, topRight:10 },
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:600px;height:400px">
   <canvas id="articulos"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Yussef, tuve que cambiar de versión, no tuve problemas y me funcionó correctamente.